# C# 'System.InvalidOperationException' Cannot mix synchronous and asynchronous operation on process stream

Tags: c#, asynchronous, command-line

I am trying to read from a CMD process repeatedly, and print out the output repeatedly as well, But the while loop I am using is inside a Task.Run so that it doesn't lock the program up, but there is some problem  with ASync and non-ASync methods that I don't quite understand. I get that I need to not have the pProcess.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd in a Task.Run, but how would I implement this in my code? Thanks!

```
Task.Run(() => 
    {
        while (true)
        {
            string output = pProcess.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
            System.Console.Write(output);
        }
     });
```

[image]

Comment: IMO you should just subscribe to the [Process.OutputDataReceived Event](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.outputdatareceived(v=vs.110).aspx), and remember to unsubscribe the event when you are done with the process, and that `process.BeginOutputReadLine();` is what starts reading the stdout (e.Data in the event handler is the standard output from the process).

Comment: Not all relevant code is provided, proven by the screenshot. In fact the error message tells us that other code is there interfering with this synchronous read. The error tells exactly what the problem is. Closing for now because the required code is missing. Also, you need to act on the answer pointing out the problem and remove the async operation call.

Answer (score 3):

Could you please try the following code snippet? `OutputDataReceived` is the method to asynchronously read process output.

```
var startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo {
    FileName = <Your Application>,
    UseShellExecute = false, // Required to use RedirectStandardOutput
    RedirectStandardOutput = true, //Required to be able to read StandardOutput
    Arguments = <Args> // Skip this if you don't use Arguments
};

using(var process = new Process { StartInfo = startInfo })
{
    process.Start();

    process.OutputDataReceived += (sender, line) =>
    {
        if (line.Data != null)
            Console.WriteLine(line.Data);
    };

    process.BeginOutputReadLine();

    process.WaitForExit();
}
```

Comment: This does not output the cmd to the Program output D:

Comment: Please, try to set `RedirectStandardOutput` to true in ProcessStartInfo. It is required to be able to read StandardOutput. I will update my example to reflect this.

Comment: Really sorry, but that still isn't working D:If you want to have a look at the code in context, here is a download link: (You will need to change the FileName to the location of the code on your computer.)  https://mega.nz/#!mt9GhCrR!A_w8o4f6jFAWOQ9evKzL9g-GyDQB3XIHI0RD1jS-vgo

Comment: Please add the code to your question instead of linking outside. That way if someone finds this useful, the code will always be with the question. External links like this will all eventually go bad.

Comment: But... If it hasn't worked, what's the point in showing everyone else? I will put my working code in the question when it is solved. Thanks for your help

Comment: Strange, it is working for me on Mac with mono. I don't have Windows by the hand, sorry. A wild guess: maybe ethminer.exe fails with error and output data are actually written to StandardError? If so, you can `RedirectStandardError = true` and then subscribe to `ErrorDataReceived` to receive error messages. I recommend you to wrap startMining into try...catch block to prevent application crashing since you starting it on background. And since you start process in background you don't need async reading. Just call `.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd()` but `RedirectsStandardOutput = true` still matters.

Comment: OK, I think this is getting us somewhere. I am getting no output in the cmd, but also no output in the program out. How do I 'Subscrbe' to ErrorDataReceived? Thanks!

Comment: I also forgot to mention, I am getting high CPU usage from ethminer.exe when I set it mining, so I think it is mining, but just not sending it's output to the command line.

Comment: Same as to `OutputDataReceived`. Set `RedirectsStandardError = true` and then `.ErrorDataReceived += (sender, args) => Console.WriteLine(args.Data);` But if you don't get error messages when you starting miner with cmd, I think you won't get them with `ErrorDataReceived` either. Maybe you need to pass some 'verbose' flag or whatever to ethminer? I really don't know what ethminer is and what output it should produce, but i checked my solution with simple command like 'ls'.

Answer (score 2):

I have solves this problem 
your are using `Standardoutput`. 
 
you must use once for one object 
`string output = pProcess.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();` 
OR

```
pProcess.BeginOutputReadLine();
```

You cannot use both at a same time on single object. So if you want to read output and wait as well while the process not complete use

```
string output = pProcess.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
```

if you do not want to read output just simple  you can use

```
pProcess.BeginOutputReadLine();
```

well you can use both according to your need but not at the same time.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming `pProcess` is an instance of `Process`, `pProcess.StandardOutput` is asynchronous, but keeps reading until the end because of the .readToEnd() method.
 I don't think you need `Task.Run` or the while loop. Check out the example at https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.beginoutputreadline%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: I've looked at that, but it again doesn't post any the lines of the cmd to the console. Here is the code I was running, was this correct?

Comment: string output = pProcess.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
            System.Console.Write(output);

            pProcess.WaitForExit();

Comment: When you say you looked at "that", what exactly were you talking about? The example in the link does everything you want, and it works. You should be able to adapt it to your purposes. If you want specific suggestions on your code, we have to see your code. You'll need to post at least from the init of the `pProcess` object.

Comment: I meant the microsoft link you sent. Here is a link to my code: https://mega.nz/#!mt9GhCrR!A_w8o4f6jFAWOQ9evKzL9g-GyDQB3XIHI0RD1jS-vgo

Comment: So I've tried putting that (The Code in the Microsoft site) into my code, but it didn't work. Here's what I have ATM: https://mega.nz/#!749WWLra!xB_tUx9NBWowpWqZQAosCAXg5h2TdNQPE-MnKqUjYy0

Answer (score 1):

There's no problem with executing this code in a seperate Task with `Task.Run` I think you're calling some asynchronous method like BeginErrorReadLine or BeginOutputReadLine somewhere before in your code. This SO answer may help: [I am trying to read the output of a process in c# but I get this message "Cannot mix synchronous and asynchronous operation on process stream."](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11460606/848765)

Comment: I was calling     pProcess.BeginOutputReadLine();     before the Task.Run(), but I removed that and it did not fix it.

Comment: Could you please also provide your related to pProcess instance. Because your case is not reproducable right now.

Comment: I have edited my code to be like @LinuxDisciple said, and have lost that code D: Sorry.