# Problems using cmd with unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, process, cmd

I'm trying to run command prompt from unity, my problem is that I can't  find a way to fetch the result, here's my code

```
Process myProcess = new Process();
myProcess.StartInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
myProcess.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
myProcess.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
myProcess.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
myProcess.StartInfo.FileName = "C:\\Windows\\system32\\cmd.exe";
string path = "C:\\Users\\Sam\\Desktop\\Test\\rubik3Sticker.generator";
myProcess.StartInfo.Arguments = "call " + path;
myProcess.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
myProcess.Start();
```

until here it gives no exceptions, but unity crashes when I try to add this:

```
while(!myProcess.StandardOutput.EndOfStream)
    print(myProcess.StandardOutput.ReadLine());
```

any kind of help would be appreciated, thanks!

Comment: If you are redirecting stdout then don't do `StandardOutput.ReadLine()`, use the event handler instead. [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/36487777/5095502) is a pretty concise version of how to do that, just use his `process.OutputDataReceived +=` line in place of your `while` loop. And be sure to call `process.BeginOutputReadLine()` to begin redirecting output through the event.

Comment: @Quantic thanks but it did not work, unity crashed again :(

Comment: Ok few things: 1) Your running, `cmd.exe call C:\\stuff.generator`, and I don't know how well redirecting stdout works through all of that. Cant you just do, `myProcess.StartInfo.FileName = "C:\\Users\\Sam\\Desktop\\Test\\rubik3Sticker.generator";`  instead? This will spawn your process directly instead of spawning it through `cmd->call` 2) your program might be crashing because the working directory is different, try doing `myProcess.StartInfo.WorkingDirectory = "C:\\Users\\Sam\\Desktop\\Test\\";` 3) I also don't know if the working directory is propagated through `cmd->call`.

Comment: @Quantic DUDE IT WORKED! YOU'RE THE BEST THANK YOU A MILLION TIMES!