# Using redirection in unity c#

Tags: c#, file, unity-game-engine, process

I'm trying to redirect the input from a file using < , which sends data from the file (input.txt)and feeds it to the program, this is the command that I run in the terminal

```
    ./rubik3Sticker.ida2 corner.bin edge1.bin edge2.bin < input.txt
```

my question is that how can I do the redirection thing in unity? here's my code that actually runs the process and accepts the parameters but when it comes to redirection, it fails :\

```
     void Start(){
     try {
     myProcess = new Process();
     myProcess.StartInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
     myProcess.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
     myProcess.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
     myProcess.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
     myProcess.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;
     myProcess.StartInfo.FileName = "C:\\Users\\sam\\Desktop\\Test\\rubik3Sticker.ida2";
     myProcess.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
     myProcess.StartInfo.WorkingDirectory = "C:\\Users\\sam\\Desktop\\Test";
     myProcess.StartInfo.Arguments = "corner.bin edge1.bin edge2.bin";
     myProcess.OutputDataReceived += new DataReceivedEventHandler((sender, e) =>
    {
        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(e.Data))
        {
            print(e.Data);
            print ("here");
        }
    });
    myProcess.Start();
    StreamWriter myStreamWriter = myProcess.StandardInput;
    String inputText = File.ReadAllText(inputFilePath);
    myStreamWriter.Write(inputText);
    myProcess.BeginOutputReadLine();
     } catch (Exception e){
         print(e);        
     }
     myProcess.WaitForExit();
}
```

any kind of help is appreciated, thanks!

Comment: I think you want to redirect [standard input](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo.redirectstandardinput(v=vs.110).aspx), so any input that comes into the program gets redirected to your event handler.

Comment: You said it works here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36578450/problems-using-cmd-with-unity What's going on. "It fails..." What fails?

Comment: at that question I wanted to run a process with parameters only, here I want to redirect the input from a file, the process itself (as I mentioned) runs and accepts parameters, it fails when I use redirection of the input @Programmer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't do standard input redirection using the *arguments*. In the command prompt, the < redirection operator actually *separates* the arguments form the standard input.

Here is how to work with standard input:

```
...
myProcess.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;
...
myProcess.Start();
StreamWriter myStreamWriter = myProcess.StandardInput;
String inputText = File.ReadAllText(inputFilePath);
myStreamWriter.Write(inputText);
```

Comment: well thanks but it didn't work :\ here's the error message 
( 
System.InvalidOperationException: Standard input has not been redirected
  at System.Diagnostics.Process.get_StandardInput () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 )

Comment: I tried to print (inputText) and it prints the content of the text file correctly, I just don't know the reason of the error message

Comment: Did you include the `...RedirectStandardInput  = true` part? You should probably update your question with the up to date code.

Comment: I updated the code, not it's not giving me an error or anything, it's just not printing the output :\ it does nothing at all!

Comment: well you're correct I put the path of another file -.- how stupid -.- it worked tho!  thanks buddy :D